# Store ROWID in Oracle OBJECT type

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying the following:

```
CREATE TYPE T_TEST AS OBJECT (
  TEST_ROWID                ROWID,
  TEST_DATA                 NUMBER(12)
);
/
```

But I get an error:

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
PLS-00530: Illegal type used for object type attribute: 'ROWID'.
```

I want to store the rowid's because they are faster than index lookups.

What is a good way for achieving the above? Casting to and from `VARCHAR2` will probably introduce as much overhead as using the index?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two errors in your type definition.

> Nonquoted identifiers cannot be Oracle SQL reserved words. Quoted identifiers can be reserved words, although this is not recommended.
>
> Note: The reserved word ROWID is an exception to this rule. You cannot
>   use the uppercase word ROWID, either quoted or nonquoted, as a column
>   name. However, you can use the uppercase word as a quoted identifier
>   that is not a column name, and you can use the word with one or more
>   lowercase letters (for example, "Rowid" or "rowid") as any quoted
>   identifier, including a column name.

So you cannot use ROWID as the variable name.

The second one is that you cannot use ROWID type. If you try you'll get PLS-00530

As I know there are CHARTOROWID / ROWIDTOCHAR functions which may help.

Comment: Sorry, the first error is a typo. It was called `TEST_ROWID` and `TEST_DATA`, then I removed the TEST suffix to "improve reading"... Will adjust.

Comment: @davor Ok, which index are you going to use? Just don't apply a function to an indexed column

Comment: Instead of `ROWID` I could use the primary key of the table (`NUMBER(20)`).

Comment: @davor I think it would be better and more safe (depending on how are you going to use this object). Oracle may change table rowids in some cases